# Apache2 does not serve ServerAlias without www

Tags: apache, apache2

This is my `sites-available/FlaskApp.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.mywebsite.design
                ServerAlias mywebsite.design
                ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`www.mywebsite.design` works when i open on the browser correctly. However when i go to `mywebsite.design` the *Ubuntu Default "It Works"* page shows up.

I followed this tutorial [Hosting a FlaskApp](https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-first-flask-web-app/)

When i tried IPAddress as the Servername like this -

```
ServerName 139.55.55.55
```

for some reason the opening the IP address on the browser opens correctly but both `www.mywebsite.design` or `mywebsite.design` don't shows the same Ubuntu Default Page

Comment: Did you reload apache?

Comment: Tried it.. doesnt work :/

Comment: is it possible that you use the domain in another config for apache?

Comment: Like where? I have only been modifying `sites-enabled/FlaskApp.conf` file. Haven't mentioned this configuration anywhere else..

Comment: Got it! for some reason `mywebsite.design`was on `/etc/hosts` file. probably because i named the project that way at some point! phew!

Answer (score 0):

I had `mywebsite.design` on `/etc/hosts` like this -

```
127.0.1.1 mywebsite.design mywebsite
```

. probably because i named the project that way at some point!

Removed it and just put my name there and it worked!